# Why is my custom ArrayAdapter not getting filled?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, retrofit2

The data is coming in fine through Retrofit, and my custom adapter (`NewsAdapter`, based on `ArrayAdapter`) was getting populated before, but I had to make some adjustments to it and I can't get it working at all now.

The idea is to get each news source available, get the articles for each specific news source, and then populate my GridView with those articles. The `articles` member on `NewsAdapter` gets filled, but not the adapter itself, from what I understand.
Here is my code, and console output that I made for checking the values:

Console output:

```
I/System.out: Source ID: nfl-news
I/System.out: Adapter count: 0
I/System.out: Response body: [pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@ca5fafc, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@cd585, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@8639fda, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@9bbac0b, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@ed5cae8, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@c4a4501, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@c6bdfa6, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@876fde7, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@3b0ad94, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@b95303d]
I/System.out: Articles count: 10
I/System.out: Source ID: espn-cric-info
I/System.out: Adapter count: 0
I/System.out: Response body: [pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@f665032, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@3ab9183, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@4b50f00, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@5a99339, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@b253d7e, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@50bc2df, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@2dc1b2c]
I/System.out: Articles count: 17
I/System.out: Source ID: fox-sports
I/System.out: Adapter count: 0
I/System.out: Response body: [pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@80729f5, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@253b38a, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@513adfb, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@385be18, pt.ismai.a26800.readr.Articles_Map@e6d7071]
I/System.out: Articles count: 22
```

**ListNewsActivity**:

```
public class ListNewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /* ... */

        // parameters for Sources endpoint
        String category = "sport";
        String language = "en";
        String country = "us";

        // Sources endpoint
        Sources_Interface client_sources = NewsAPI_Adapter.createService(Sources_Interface.class);
        Call<Sources_Map> call_sources = client_sources.getData(category, language, country);

        call_sources.enqueue(new Callback<Sources_Map>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Sources_Map> call_sources, Response<Sources_Map> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    final NewsAdapter nAdapter = new NewsAdapter(ListNewsActivity.this,
                            R.layout.article_layout);

                    for (final Sources_Content source : response.body().sources) {
                        if (source.sortBysAvailable.contains("latest")) {

                            // Articles endpoint
                            NewsAPI_Interface client = NewsAPI_Adapter.createService(NewsAPI_Interface.class);
                            Call<NewsAPI_Map> call = client.getData(source.id, "apiKeyHere");

                            call.enqueue(new Callback<NewsAPI_Map>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<NewsAPI_Map> call, Response<NewsAPI_Map> response) {
                                    if (response.body() != null) {
                                        ExpandableHeightGridView gv_content = (ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.gv_content);
                                        nAdapter.addAll(response.body().articles);
                                        System.out.println("Source ID: " + source.id + "\n" +
                                                "Adapter count: " + nAdapter.getCount() + "\n" +
                                                "Response body: " + response.body().articles + "\n" +
                                                "Articles count: " + nAdapter.articles.size() + "\n");
                                        gv_content.setAdapter(nAdapter);
                                        gv_content.setExpanded(true);
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<NewsAPI_Map> call, Throwable t) {
                                    System.out.println("An error ocurred!\n" +
                                            "URL: " + call.request().url() + "\n" +
                                            "Cause: " + t.getCause().toString());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Sources_Map> call_sources, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("An error ocurred!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**NewsAdapter**:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Articles_Map> {
    Context mContext;
    List<Articles_Map> articles;

    public NewsAdapter(Context c, int resource) {
        super(c, resource);
        this.mContext = c;
        this.articles = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public NewsAdapter(Context c, int resource, List<Articles_Map> articles) {
        super(c, resource, articles);
        this.mContext = c;
        this.articles = articles;
    }

    public void addAll(List<Articles_Map> articles) {
        if (this.articles == null) {
            this.articles = new ArrayList<>(articles);
        } else {
            this.articles.addAll(articles);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // get the property we are displaying
        Articles_Map article = articles.get(position);

        // get the inflater and inflate the XML layout for each item
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_layout, null);

        ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(article.urlToImage).into(thumbnail);
        title.setText(article.title);
        description.setText(article.description);

        return view;
    }
}
```

**NewsAPI_Map**:

```
public class NewsAPI_Map {
    String status;
    String source;
    List<Articles_Map> articles;

    public NewsAPI_Map(String status, String source, List<Articles_Map> articles) {
        this.status = status;
        this.source = source;
        this.articles = articles;
    }
}
```

**Articles_Map**:

```
public class Articles_Map {
    String title;
    String description;
    String url;
    String urlToImage;

    public Articles_Map(String title, String description, String url, String urlToImage) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.url = url;
        this.urlToImage = urlToImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Adapter count: 0` looks odd

Comment: And you shouldn't need to implement your own `addAll` method to `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: @cricket_007 If I don't implement my own `addAll`, the app crashes with an `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0` error, so that's why I tried doing it this way.

Comment: I think it's because you didn't call this constructor to setup the ArrayList. `super(c, resource, articles)`. You just called `new NewsAdapter(ListNewsActivity.this, R.layout.article_layout);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something about `getCount` is returning 0, and so the adapter thinks it shouldn't be displaying data into the list. I believe this is because you called the constructor which does not initialize the underlying `List` with the `articles` data list that you have in that class.

You shouldn't need to define your own List within your adapter implementation, though. The `ArrayAdapter` super class has one.

So, remove those references. (You also don't really need the Context since `getContext()` is available).

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Articles_Map> {
    Context mContext;

    public NewsAdapter(Context c, int resource) {
        super(c, resource);
        this.mContext = c;
    }

    public NewsAdapter(Context c, int resource, List<Articles_Map> articles) {
        super(c, resource, articles);
        this.mContext = c;
    }
```

Then, in `getView`, use `getItem(position)` instead.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // get the property we are displaying
    Articles_Map article = getItem(position);
```

And you can still use `adapter.add` or `adapter.addAll`, which does add to the underlying `List` and notifies the dataset.

Comment: Thanks! Both yours and Anto's solutions worked, but yours seemed cleaner and made more sense than what I had before, so I chose your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Not a problem. I'd also suggest looking up the ViewHolder pattern to optimize your ListView (or switch to a RecyclerView)

Comment: Thanks again, I'll check that out later after I'm done coding what I'm doing at the moment. Although I'm guessing in my case I should use the RecyclerView, since I'm using a custom GridView and not a ListView like you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Try inserting the `getCount()` method :

```
@Override
public int getCount(){
    int size = articles == null ? 0 : articles.size();
    return size;
}
```